# Minify HTML matrix laid out design (only Pure CSS and HTML)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a logo with pure HTML and CSS. The design is pretty straightforward. A [13x13] matrix with some colored items.

The CSS is very simple and minor. But the HTML code, on the other hand, has so much repeating code and needs to be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)ed out.

```css
body { width: 100vmin; margin: auto }
logo {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 1fr);
}

s { }
w { background-color: #d6d6d6; aspect-ratio: 1 }
l { background-color: #d6d6d6; aspect-ratio: 1 }
f { background-color: #d6d6d6; aspect-ratio: 1 }
```

```html
<logo>
<f></f><f></f><f></f><s></s><f></f><f></f><f></f><s></s><f></f><s></s><f></f><f></f><f></f>
<f></f><s></s><f></f><s></s><s></s><s></s><f></f><s></s><f></f><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s>
<f></f><s></s><f></f><s></s><f></f><f></f><f></f><s></s><f></f><s></s><f></f><s></s><f></f>
<f></f><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><f></f><s></s><s></s><s></s><f></f>
<f></f><s></s><l></l><l></l><l></l><l></l><l></l><s></s><f></f><s></s><f></f><s></s><f></f>
<f></f><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><f></f><s></s><f></f>
<f></f><s></s><l></l><l></l><l></l><l></l><l></l><l></l><s></s><f></f><f></f><s></s><f></f>
<f></f><s></s><l></l><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s>
<f></f><s></s><l></l><s></s><l></l><l></l><l></l><s></s><w></w><s></s><w></w><s></s><w></w>
<s></s><s></s><l></l><s></s><s></s><s></s><l></l><s></s><s></s><s></s><w></w><s></s><s></s>
<l></l><l></l><l></l><s></s><l></l><l></l><l></l><w></w><w></w><w></w><w></w><s></s><w></w>
<l></l><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><s></s><w></w>
<l></l><l></l><l></l><l></l><l></l><l></l><l></l><l></l><l></l><l></l><s></s><w></w><w></w>
</logo>
```

I've already tried `<f/>` instead of `<f></f>` with no luck.

Is there any way to reduce this code?

**Note:** The colors should be kept.

Comment: that's definitely not the right method to do it. Read about canvas, gradient, SVG, etc. There are a lot of method more suitable to draw stuff

Comment: This question is too broad for SO. HTML was never intended to be an art canvas anyway.

Comment: The problem with this design is that there's no tooling for it and no graphics department would ever design or support a logo made this way. In contrast, SVG is widely used and there is lots of expertise and professional tools.

Answer (score 2):

If javascript is ok, you can concatenate the types of cells into a string object and use it to dynamically build the logo. Sample code is below.

```js
let logo = document.getElementById("logo"); 
logo.dataset["cells"].split('').forEach(a => logo.append(document.createElement(a)));
```

```css
body { width: 100vmin; margin: auto }
logo {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 1fr);
}

w { background-color: #d6d6d6; aspect-ratio: 1 }
l { background-color: #d6d6d6; aspect-ratio: 1 }
f { background-color: #d6d6d6; aspect-ratio: 1 }
```

```html
<logo id="logo" data-cells="fffsfffsfsffffsfsssfsfssssfsfsfffsfsfsffsssssssfsssffslllllsfsfsffsssssssssfsffsllllllsffsffslssssssssssfslslllswswswsslssslssswsslllslllwwwwswlssssssssssswllllllllllsww"></logo>
```

Per the need for HTML/CSS only solution and @Temani Afif's comment, here is a SVG solution:

```css
    .w * { stroke:red;stroke-width:1;;fill:none;stroke-linejoin="miter"; }
    .l * { stroke:green;stroke-width:1;;fill:none;stroke-linejoin="miter"; }
    .f * { stroke:blue;stroke-width:1;;fill:none;stroke-linejoin="miter"; }
```

```html
<logo>
    <svg height="300" width="300" viewBox="-1 -1 15 15">
        <g class="w">
            <path d="M12.5,10 L12.5,12.5 L11,12.5" />
            <path d="M6.5,10.5 L10.5,10.5 L10.5,8" />
            <path d="M8,8.5 L9,8.5" />
            <path d="M12,8.5 L13,8.5" />
        </g>
        <g class="l">
            <path d="M4,8.5 L6.5,8.5 L6.5,10.5 L4,10.5" />
            <path d="M7,4.5 L2,4.5" />
            <path d="M8,6.5 L2.5,6.5 L2.5,10.5 L0.5,10.5 L0.5,12.5 L10,12.5" />
        </g>
        <g class="f">
            <path d="M0.5,9 L0.5,0.5 L2.5,0.5 L2.5,3" />
            <path d="M4,0.5 L6.5,0.5 L6.5,2.5 L4,2.5" />
            <path d="M8.5,0 L8.5,5" />
            <path d="M10,0.5 L13,0.5" />
            <path d="M10,2.5 L11,2.5" />
            <path d="M12.5,2 L12.5,7" />
            <path d="M10.5,4 L10.5,6.5 L9,6.5" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</logo>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need pure HTML and CSS only. But +1 for the answer. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! Btw, w l and f all have the same background color in your CSS code. Is it the case?

Comment: Yes but, I masked colors with a gray color because of some restrictions in the sharing the code.

Comment: Updated the answer with a SVG solution

Comment: I have to up vote since it's nearly the same as the solution I was about to post. Also, the SVG is only 900 bytes compared to OP's html logo which is 1.5kb. Bravo - well done.